# Проверка данных вводимых в форму

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как здесь можно добавить проверку пароля и емайл адреса? Код формы и javascript ниже.

```
<form id="formreg" action="save_user.php" method="post">
    <h3>Регистрация на сайте!</h3>
    <p>
        <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Введите Login') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Введите Login';" value="Введите Login" class="reg" name="user_name" id="username"/>
        <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span><br />Должен быть не менее 3 и не более 15 знаков!
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="pass" onfocus="if(this.value=='Введите пароль') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Введите пароль';" value="Введите пароль" type="password" class="reg" name="password" />
        <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
        <br />Пароль должен быть не менее 6 и не более 15 знаков!
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='Ваш E-mail') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Ваш E-mail';" value="Ваш E-mail" id="validate" class="reg" name="email" />
        <span id="validEmail" style="display:none"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="FILE" class="ava" name="fupload"><br />Изображение должно быть формата jpg, gif или png:
    </p>
    <p>
        <p><img src="code/my_codegen.php"></p>
        <input onfocus="if(this.value=='Введите код') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Введите код';" value="Введите код" class="reg" type="text" name="code">
    </p>

<!-- В code/my_codegen.php генерируется код и рисуется изображение -->

    <p>
    <p>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" />
    </p>
</form>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#username").blur(function()
    {
        $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Проверка...').fadeIn("slow");

        // Проверить существует ли имя
        $.post("user.php",{ user_name:$(this).val() } ,function(data)
        {
            if (data=='no') // Если имя не доступно
            {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() // Начнет появляться сообщение
                { 
                    $(this).html('Этот Login уже занят').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                }); 
            }
            else 
            if (data=='menee') // Если имя не доступно
            {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() // Начнет появляться сообщение
                { 
                    $(this).html('Login не подходит').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() 
                { 
                    // Тут прописывается сообщение о доступности имени
                    $(this).html('Login доступен для регистрации').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1); 
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: @zhekonya Уважаемый участник, используйте возможности редактора для форматирования кода.

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не использовать нативную проверку ?

```
<input type="email" required />
<input type="password" required placeholder ="Введите пароль"/>
```

placeholder - опциональный параметр

Comment: Добавлю не очевидную для многих вещь. Проверка на стороне пользователя не освобождает вас от проверки на сервере. Не забывайте про безопасность.

Answer (score 0):

необходимо использовать jQuery и Ajax как написано тут: linkexchanger.su/2008/46.html